# Is there a way to change resource authentication method to external via API?

Tags: google-iap

Say I've added a new resource to protect with IAP, and a new tenant. I want to do this for each new client that I onboard, to use external identities, and allow them to control their own users. I can't be logging into the cloud console each time to add a new client (I can see that users for a tenant can be managed by API). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

have you evaluated using Identity Platform with IAP for authentication, https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs? At the IAP-protected resource, you may change the auth to use IdP instead of the default Google Auth.

With IdP you can leverage the external identities of multiple providers that your customer would control.